# Appium test a Ionic5 app to run on Aws Device Farm?

Tags: ionic-framework, appium, aws-device-farm

I have a app written with Ionic 5. I want to be able to test it on AWS Farm, so I need to setup Appium tests to work. I have found https://marckassay.github.io/test/automation/2019/03/28/ionic-angular-with-appium.html but its for Ionic 4.

Any pointers?

Comment: Seems like most of the steps to setting up Ionic with Appium is outlined through that blog. One of the [Ionic doc pages](https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/versioning) states that upgrading between 4 and 5 has been made easy. Therefore, the webdriverio and Appium steps outlined in that blog should be relatively the same with 5 as it is with 4. Are you running into any issues?

Comment: @TobeE I have managed to make the blog example to work on my machine which is nice already. I havent managed to run on my app though. i am planning to migrate the example from 4 to 5 as you sad. and then migrating the code over. hope it works. will post the updates I have on the upcoming days. I was hoping someone have a Ionic5 Appium repo setup somewhere ready.

Comment: @CESCO If you need help running the tests on Device Farm please reach out to aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com I can help you out.